# Double to string conversion different for .NET Framework and .NET Core

Tags: c#, json.net, double, precision

**Project File:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>[see below]</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Code:**

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription);
var d = 0.41237361717224119D;
Console.WriteLine(d);
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);
Console.WriteLine(json);
d = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<double>(json);
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

**Output (TargetFramework = netcoreapp3.1, without breakpoints):**

```
.NET Core 3.1.4
0.4123736171722412
0.4123736171722412
0.4123736171722412
```

**Output (TargetFramework = netcoreapp3.1, with breakpoints):**

```
.NET Core 3.1.4
0.4123736171722496
0.4123736171722496
0.4123736171722496
```

**Output (TargetFramework = net48, with/without breakpoints):**

```
.NET Framework 4.8.4250.0
0.412373617172241
0.41237361717224119
0.412373617172241
```

There is no other code in `Main(string[] args)` inside `Program.cs`.
I'm using JetBrains Rider to run this.
As you can see, the double to string conversion is different, depending on

- the target .NET framework used (.NET Framework 4.8 vs. .NET Core 3.1)
- whether breakpoints are set within the code or not
- whether it is done with Console.WriteLine or Json.NET serializer

Can someone explain why this double to string conversion is so different depending on so many factors?
Shouldn't this operation be well-defined or specified?
What other factors are there? CPU or microarchitecture?

Comment: Are you using a different version of Json.NET?

Comment: I added the .csproj for clarification, I'm using Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3 NuGet package both times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it's because of [Floating-Point Parsing and Formatting improvements in .NET Core 3.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/).

You could address this by specifying the format, for example:

```
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("G15"));
```